# Select drop down from table array

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Here is part of my controller;

```
$agreements = Agreement::all();

print_r($agreements) //this works and displays an object/array with the details!

return View::make('individual_agreements.create') 
  ->with('individual', $individual)
  ->with('agreements', $agreements)
  ->with('content_title', 'Create new individual agreement');
```

Here is part of my view;

```
<div class="form-group">
  {{ Form::label('agreement_name', 'Agreement name') }}
  {{ Form::select('agreement_name', $agreements->agreement_name) }}
</div>
```

I have a field called agreement_name in the table.. All I want to do is turn that in to a dropdown in the most efficient Laravel/Eloquent way as possible.

I keep getting the standard "agreement_name not defined" error and I cannot find a suitable example anywhere online having looked for over an hour now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you need the agreements for something else on the same page** try

```
<div class="form-group">
  {{ Form::label('agreement_name', 'Agreement name') }}
  {{ Form::select('agreement_name', $agreements->lists('agreement_name', 'agreement_name')) }}
</div>
```

This will get all the agreements names within your agreements collection and allow them to be used within the select drop down. First parameter is the column and second is the key.

Else just change your query to;

```
$agreements = Agreement::lists('agreement_name', 'id');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this

```
$agreements = Agreement::lists('agreement_name', 'id');
```

`all` return you all columns in table, so that's why your code wont work

Answer (score 0):

The way you have this set up allows for the use of a `foreach` loop to list through and display results:

```
<select name="agreement_name" class="">
  <option value="">- Select -</option>
  @foreach($agreements AS $agreement)
  <option value="{{ $agreement->id }}">{{ $agreement->agreement_name }}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

Since your `$agreements` is an array of elements, calling `$agreements->agreement_name` wouldn't work, while `$agreements[0]->agreement_name` probably would. If you want to use the `Form::select()` option, you'll need to use a different method of getting your agreements. Check the other answers for that solution.

Hope this provided some insight!

**Edit**

I should note that this isn't the *Laravel Way* of doing things, but it is certainly viable.